# Installing apache as a "manual" service (service that must not start automatically during the boot process)

Tags: apache, service

I am trying to install Apache as a manual service as I don't want it to start automatically during the boot process.

When Apache is installed as a service by `httpd -k install -n "apache_2.x"`, it starts automatically during the boot process which is not required. Like MariaDB/MySQL can be installed as a manual service by `mysqld --install-manual "mariadb_10.x"`, can someone tell me how you install Apache as a manual service?

I also found out that Apache takes an argument called `config` as `httpd -k config` which is said to "change startup Options of an Apache service" (as quoted in `httpd -h`). I speculate that this option can help change the startup behavior. Can someone also please enlighten me on this argument?

Thanks in advance.